# How to add View/Create function in MVC and update it into index?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, crud

I'm still new to MVC but really curious about it. I have my create view function, but I was wondring why Im not be able to show new data that I create back to my index?

here is my controller:

```
       //GET /UserActivity/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        UserActivityModels ua = new UserActivityModels();
        return View(userActivity);
    }


    //
    // POST: /UserActivity/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        try
        {
             UserActivityModels ua = new UserActivityModels();


             ua.Id = Int32.Parse(formCollection["Id"]);
             ua.CreatedBy = Int32.Parse(formCollection["CreatedBy"]);
             ua.CreatedOn = DateTime.Parse(formCollection["CreatedOn"]);
             ua.ModifiedBy = Int32.Parse(formCollection["ModifiedBy"]);
             ua.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Parse(formCollection["ModifiedOn"]);
             ua.ContactId = formCollection["ContactId"];
             ua.StatusCode = Int32.Parse(formCollection["StatusCode"]);
             ua.StateCode = Int32.Parse(formCollection["StateCode"]);
             ua.EntityName = formCollection["EntityName"];
             ua.EntityId = Int32.Parse(formCollection["EntityId"]);
             ua.ActivityType = Int32.Parse(formCollection["ActivityType"]);
             ua.ActivityStatus = formCollection["ActivityStatus"];

             ua.DueDate = DateTime.Parse(formCollection["DueDate"]);

             ua.ActualEndDate = DateTime.Parse(formCollection["ActualEndDate"]);

             ua.MasqueradeOn = DateTime.Parse(formCollection["MasqueradeOn"]);

             ua.MasqueradeBy = Int32.Parse(formCollection["MasqueradeBy"]);


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        catch
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

the model:

```
 public class UserActivityModels
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public string ContactId { get; set; }

    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public int StateCode { get; set; }

    public int ActivityType { get; set; }

    public string ActivityStatus { get; set; }

    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ActualEndDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime MasqueradeOn { get; set; }

    public int MasqueradeBy { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    //public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    // public List<string> userActivity { get; set; }

}
```

Does anyone could tell me why when I click "submit" button, the new created data is now showing in the index? Thanks

and Here is the View/Index:

```
            @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMain.cshtml";

     }

     <h2>Index</h2>

         @*<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>*@

     <h3>User Activity</h3>
      @using (Html.BeginForm("index", null, FormMethod.Get))
       {
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="input-group">

            <input type="text"
                   name="filter"
                   value="@ViewBag.filter"
                   class="form-control"
                   style="display: inline"
                   placeholder="Search by Contact Name or Entity Name" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go</button>
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right col-lg-1">
        <a class="btn btn-success" data-modal="" href="/UserActivity/Create" id="btnCreate">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top:5px;">
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(
                    Model,
                    canPage: true,
                    rowsPerPage: 5,
                    canSort: true);
        //ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

   //grid.Bind(Model, rowCount: (int)ViewData["totalCount"], autoSortAndPage: false);

        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

        @grid.GetHtml(
       htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
    // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
    fillEmptyRows: false,
    tableStyle: "table table-striped",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns: grid.Columns(
      //grid.Column("Id", "Id"),
      grid.Column("Id", "Id", style: "col-lg-1", canSort: true),
      grid.Column("CreatedBy", "CreatedBy", style: "col-lg-6"),
      grid.Column("CreatedOn", header: "CreatedOn", style: "col-lg-2", canSort: true),
      grid.Column("ModifiedBy", header: "ModifiedBy", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("ModifiedOn", header: "ModifiedOn", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("ContactId", header: "ContactId", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("EntityName", header: "EntityName", style: "col-lg-2"),
      //grid.Column("EntityName", "EntityName", style: "col-lg-1", canSort: true),
      grid.Column("EntityId", header: "EntityId", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("StatusCode", header: "StatusCode", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("StateCode", header: "StateCode", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("ActivityType", header: "ActivityType", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("ActivityStatus", header: "ActivityStatus", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("DueDate", header: "DueDate", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("ActualEndDate", header: "ActualEndDate", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("MasqueradeOn", header: "MasqueradeOn", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("MasqueradeBy", header: "MasqueradeBy", style: "col-lg-2"),
      grid.Column("ContactName", header: "ContactName", style: "col-lg-2"),
      //grid.Column("ContactName", "ContactName", style: "col-lg-1", canSort: true),



      grid.Column(header: "Action", canSort: false, style: "action",
 format: @<text>
        @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/UserActivity/Details/" + item.Id + "' id='" + item.Id + "' title='Detail'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'> </span> </a>")
        @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/UserActivity/Edit/" + item.Id + "' id='" + item.Id + "' title='Edit'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'> </span> </a>")
        @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/UserActivity/Delete/" + item.Id + "' id='" + item.Id + "' title='Delete'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span> </a>")
</text>)

    ));
    }

</div>
        }
```

Comment: What `Index()`? And why do you have `return View("Index");` in the `catch` block. And please go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics. You POST method should be `UserActivityModels model`, not `FormCollection formCollection` (you should never have to use `FormCollection`). And nowhere do you ever save the data!

Comment: the  Index here mean for ~/Views/Shared/Index. So in the create.cshtml, I want to create new data then stored in into database and show the new data into Index when button "submit" is clicked. I wondering why the new data is not stored to db? and I provide the create.cshtml in the question already @StephenMuecke

Comment: Nowhere in you `Create` POST method do you ever save the data anywhere. How would you expect it to be displayed when you redirect t another method (an you have not even shown that method!). Go to the MVC site and learn the basics

Comment: Yes Sir! I was just curios about this MVC thing and mysql @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `Index` method, you would have to retrieve the model you created in the `Create` method, and use that as an argument when returning the view.

One way to pass a model from one controller method to another is to use the `TempData` dictionary.

So what you can do is this: In your `Create` method, just before calling `return RedirectToAction("Index");`, store your model in `TempData`:

```
TempData["MyModel"] = ua;
```

Then, in the `Index` method, retrieve the model from `TempData` and pass it into the view:

```
var myModel = (UserActivityModels)TempData["MyModel"];

return View(myModel);
```

Comment: I tried mate. But it turns out, there is a problem with the datagrid. the error said,"A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed." any idea how? :(

Comment: You might have to open a different question for that. But, can you tell me where you are using a data grid? In the Index view? I thought you were using html helpers (`EditorFor`, `LabelFor`, etc.)?

Comment: yeah, I use datagrid in the index. I have updated my index on the question. Thanks